# How to block file types from upload?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Actually, my problem is quite simple but I couldn't find an answer.

I have a list of file types and I don't want any files other than this list to be uploaded to my bucket. I want to block anything other than this list.

Is there any way I can do this?

I know there is such a restriction in Oracle, but is there such a thing in Google Cloud Storage?

List example:

```
[
    ".mp4",
    ".mov",
    ".jpeg",
    ".zip",
    ...
    ".jpg"
]
```

Comment: The file extension does not indicate the actual file type. You must read the file to determine the format. Users can upload images and use any file extension they want.

Comment: How can I determine the type of file by reading it? Can you show an example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cloud functions to handle events like adding new files in a bucket. You can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) on how to do that.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you very much. I managed to do file type control with cloud functions. However, It's not secure. You can upload anything with a signed url even the extension is valid. I need to do a virus scanned after the file uploaded. Now I'm looking for that